# JQuery Datetime picker not displaying desired date format

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

I am facing a strange jQuery problem, I am trying to save date into the database.

On the UI i am using jquery date-time picker from jQuery version 2.x.

The problem is:

**When i enter  the date as 04/07/2015 (4th July 2015), it is taking it as 07/04/2015 (7th April 2015). I have specified the Datetime format as "dd/mm/yyyy".**

I have added onclick event on textbox as :

```
$(this).datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", changeMonth : true, changeYear : true,  }).datepicker("show");
```

I am referencing jquery.ui.min.js with Jquery-2.1.4.min.js

My View code for the textbox is as:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, String.Format("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @placeholder=DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), @class = "form-control dropDawnLabel date_Picker", @ID = "expancesDate", @onBlur = "dateVal()", @onkeypress = "return blockSpecialCharDate(event)" })
```

Comment: Please add code that can be used to reproduce your problem. Do you initialise the `datetimepicker` with the desired date format? Try this: `$(".selector").datetimepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});`.

Comment: Hi Matthias, i added some code, please have a look.

Comment: the script looks fine. what are you doing in the `dateVal()` function?

Comment: Hi Sushil.  I am using dateval() function just for validation to check null values for date field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I was able to help the guy again. Basically, the question should "Datetime format problem in ASP.NET MVC with ORACLE backend"

We changed the dateFormat to `yyyy-MM-dd` from `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Also, in backend in C#, he was parsing the date string into DateTime Variable. So we changed the Datetime Culture there as well to `yyyy-MM-dd` and problem was resolved.